# How to get the elements of the list to interact with each other?

Tags: python

```
 BMI= weight in kg/ height in meters**2

print(person_data2)
[['John', 84.9, 184],
 ['Ryan', 81.8, 177],
 ['Bobby', 86.1, 190],
 ['Pete', 92.2, 188],
 ['Esther', 69.6, 159],
 ['Jane', 72.0, 166],
 ['Samantha', 51.3, 162]]

for p, person in enumerate (person_data2):
  person_data2[p][2]=person_data2[p][2]/100
print (person_data2)

for p, person in enumerate (person_data2):
```

I can't seem to get past this part. I got the height divided by 100 to figure out how many meters tall each person is, but now I cannot create a for loop for the BMI equation. I've tried

```
for p, person in enumerate (person_data2):
   person_data2[p][1][2]=person_data2[p][1]/[2]**2  #and I have tried
for p, person in enumerate (person_data2):
  person_data2[p][1][2]=person_data2[p][1]/[p][2]**2
```

Comment: You don't need `enumerate()` it's just making things more complex. Just `for person in person_data2:` then in the loop `person` will be the inner list. Also, it's helpful in questions like this to add what your expected outcome is. Do you want a new list? Append to the existing list? etc...

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "interact with each other"?

Comment: For each list field that you want to address via an index, you need to write out the name of the list. Instead of `data[1] / [2]`, you'll need to write `data[1] / data[2]`.

Comment: Otherwise, `[2]` is a list literal with the element `2` in it.

Comment: What exactly would that look like in this case? I tried that and got a " 'float' object is not subscriptable" error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lambda function for this

```
BMI= weight in kg/ height in meters**2

 print(person_data2)
 li = [['John', 84.9, 184],
 ['Ryan', 81.8, 177],
 ['Bobby', 86.1, 190],
 ['Pete', 92.2, 188], 
['Esther', 69.6, 159],
 ['Jane', 72.0, 166],
 ['Samantha', 51.3, 162]]

listOfBMIs= list(map(lambda x:x[1]/(x[-1]/100),li))
print(listOfBMIs)
```

#### Explanation:

When you say `lambda x:x+1`, this means it takes a number and adds one to it.

When you say `map(lambda x:x+1,[1,2,3,4])`:

Map takes every element of the array and maps it to the lambda function, so every element is taken and added one to it.

Similarly, in your question, we are taking each element of your array of arrays.
Putting it in lambda function like so:

`lambda x:x[1]/(x[-1]/100)`
can be seen like

`lambda ['John', 84.9, 184] : 84.9/(184 /100)`

for the first iteration. Similarly for the second iteration and so on...

#### Addon..

A faster way could be to do just this

`listOfBMIs= [i[1]/(i[-1]/100) for i in li]`

Sometimes, lambda within a map slows it down where normal forloop rules.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why lambda/map instead of the pythonic list-comprehension?

Comment: You can have a look at this, its a trade off, for some cases map with lambda is better and for some cases its not. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-map-vs-list-comprehension/

Comment: The main advantage of using `map` is to have an iterator and avoid creating an actual list in memory. But you are doing `list(map(...))` so that loses the point of `map` and would bemuch more readable using a simple list-comp. Your `list(map(lambda x:x[1]/(x[-1]/100),li))` becomes a simple `[x[1]/(x[-1]/100) for x in li]`

Comment: Thanks megalng and Tomerikoo for your comments. I have already added that to the answer.